# Extrude in python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, extrude, bmesh

As in title, I'm trying to extrude mesh via python as I have ~1.5k objects to extrude and when I do it in editor it works perfectly but when I run it via python it always go wrong. It just move face and I'm missing one face. So I tried to create it but I can create only half of it for some reason. Can somebody help?

Code:

```
import bpy, bmesh

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.name.startswith("Exterior"): # Name
        print(obj.name)
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

        # Go to edit mode, face selection mode and select all faces
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )     # Toggle edit mode
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type = 'FACE' )    # Change to face selection
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'SELECT' ) # Select all faces

        # As extrude move forward base face it needs to be saved
        bm = bmesh.new() # create an empty BMesh        
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
        meshVertices = [e for e in bm.verts]    

        # Flip normals
        #bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals() 

        # Extrude 
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move( 
            MESH_OT_extrude_faces_indiv={"mirror": True}, 
            TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value": -0.4,   # Dirrection and size of extrude
            "mirror": False,
            "proportional": 'DISABLED',
            "proportional_edit_falloff": 'SMOOTH',
            "proportional_size": 1,
            "snap": False,
            "snap_target": 'CLOSEST',
            "snap_point": (0, 0, 0),
            "snap_align": False,
            "snap_normal": (0, 0, 0),
            "release_confirm": False}) 

        # Add face 
        bm.faces.new(meshVertices) # len(meshVertices)

        # Update & Destroy BMESH
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data) # Write the bmesh back to the mesh
        bm.free()  # free and prevent further access

        # At end recalculate UV
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()

        # Switch back to Object at end
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )

        # Origin
        #bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
```

Mesh to be extruded.

[image: Mesh to extrude]

Extruded mesh.

[image: Extruded mesh]

Second side of extruded mesh.

[image: Extruded mesh problem]

PS: Mesh is just a 4 vertices square (one face) and I'm trying to make it 3d from 2d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done it.
Here is code if anyone is interested:

```
import bpy, bmesh

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
if obj.name.startswith("Exterior.462"): # Name
    print(obj.name)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

    # Go to edit mode, face selection mode and select all faces
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )     # Toggle edit mode
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type = 'FACE' )    # Change to face selection
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'SELECT' ) # Select all faces

    # Create Bmesh
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( bpy.context.object.data )

    # Extude Bmesh
    for f in bm.faces:
        face = f.normal
    r = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=bm.faces[:])
    verts = [e for e in r['geom'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
    TranslateDirection = face * 1 # Extrude Strength/Length
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec = TranslateDirection, verts=verts)

    # Update & Destroy Bmesh
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data) # Write the bmesh back to the mesh
    bm.free()  # free and prevent further access

    # Flip normals
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
    bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals() 

    # At end recalculate UV
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()

    # Switch back to Object at end
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )

    # Origin to center
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
```

Comment: pls accept your own answer

Comment: Thanks for code, just to note that since Blender 2.8 :  change      bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
to   bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj, from https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-set-object-mesh-to-active-in-blender-2-8-python-api/